# New page in iTextSharp

Tags: vb.net, itext

I'm trying to create a PDF with `iTextSharp` which reads the values out of a form, which are inserted from a `DataGridView`.
So, after a specific amount of lines of the `DataGridView` I want to create a new page with `PdfFile.NewPage()`

This code writes the `DataGridView` into a PDF:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
    For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        pdfcell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString(), pTable))
        PdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT
        PdfTable.AddCell(pdfcell)
    Next
Next
PdfFile.Add(PdfTable)
```

The reason for doing that is because the `DataGridView` overwrites the footer.

After 20 `DataGridView` lines a `PdfFile.NewPage()` should follow. On the second page it should continue with the 21 `DataGridView` lines.
For example after 50 lines a new page.

This is the code for the footer:

```
Inherits PdfPageEventHelper
Public Overrides Sub OnendPage(ByVal writer As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter, ByVal document As iTextSharp.text.Document)
    Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)
    Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent
    cb.BeginText()
    cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12)
    cb.SetTextMatrix(50, 30)
    cb.ShowText("TEXTTEXT " & writer.PageNumber)
    cb.EndText()
```

I already tried this. It is just creating the next page but still overwrites the footer:

```
      For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
         For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            pdfcell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString(), pTable))
            PdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT
            PdfTable.AddCell(pdfcell)
         Next
         Select Case i
            Case 20, 30, 60, 99
               PdfFile.NewPage()
         End Select
      Next
      PdfFile.Add(PdfTable)
```

Comment: Please take a rest. Then look at your code with a clear head. You'll discover that your code doesn't make any sense. You'll throw away your code, and you'll start anew.

Comment: For instance: you create a `PdfPTable` instance. As long as you don't add this `PdfTable` to the document (`PdfFile.Add(PdfTable)`), no content is rendered. In your code, you are trying to create a new page *before* any table content is added. Obviously, this doesn't work, because the `NewPage()` method is ignored if no content was added to the current page.

Comment: One also might wonder why you'd want to arbitrarily invoke a new page after row 20, 30, 60, 99. How do you know if there's sufficient room on the page for 20 rows, 10 rows, 30 rows, 49 rows? Wouldn't you rather leave the distribution of rows over different pages to iText? If not, you have to measure the height of each row. You might want to avoid that.

Comment: Obviously, if you *need* a page break after each of those specific rows, you'd better create separate tables, and add them separately with a page break in-between. It's not really a matter of "knowing how to use iText." It's a matter of elementary logic.

Comment: I removed the `visual-studio-2015` tag as although you may be using that to code with it's not relevant to the question. Tag info _Visual Studio 2015 is the version of Microsoft's Visual Studio product suite which follows 2013 version. Do not use this tag unless you have a specific question about Visual Studio -- not just a coding issue._